# MVC: return View() is going back to http ActionResult instead of rendering View

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

I have a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.VerifiedBy)<dt>
        <dd>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VerifiedBy)</dd>
    </dl>
    <input type="submit" value="Verify" onclick="checkValueVerify();" />
}
```

If the user clicks the Verify button without entering a value for Verified by, the JavaScript function checkValueVerify will send an alert and then direct to the HttpPost Verify ActionResult.

JavaScript:

```
function checkValueVerify() {
    if (document.getElementById("verifiedBy").value== "") {
         alert('Must enter name of verifier');
    } 
    $.ajax({
        url: '/GAC/Verify',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'by': verifBy}
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Verify(GACVerifyViewModel viewModel,string by)
{
    if(by==null)
        {
            //code                
            return View();
        }
```

When I step through the code, it goes from `return View` to Verify.cshtml to Layout.cshtml which is what I expect.  However, at the end of Layout.cshtml, it goes back to `[HttpPost] Verify` and my parameter is null at this point.

So the flow is HttpPost Verify -> Verify.cshtml -> HttpPost Verify (controller -> view -> controller.
Why is it going back to my HttpPost ActionResult Verify in the controller instead of just rendering the view?

Comment: So if the user does NOT enter a value, do you want the form submitted?

Comment: I do but I'm only having problems with the part where they don't enter a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because your form sends a post back request and submits the form, you should prevent default behavior of submit button. 
simply add `event.preventDefault` or `return false` at the end of javascript function

Answer (score 0):

What I believe is happening here is that your form is being posted twice.

Once via the Ajax call and then again via the standard submit input.

a simple fix should be to add return false eg:

```
<input type="submit" value="Verify" onclick="checkValueVerify(); return false;" />
```

The return false is to stop the submit input posting the form so that only the Ajax function will post.